# Visual Studio acting like a reference is missing, but it is clearly there,

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studios 2015 Community.
I was given this code to work on and improve, and I cant get any thing from MetroFramework to behave properly. This is my first time using VS, but my research has been extensive, and I am very stuck. Any time I try to open up a design, I am met with many many errors that you can see in the gallery.

So naturally I follow up and check my references. The references in this project clearly show MetroFramework.

And furthermore, Metroframework.Controls clearly shows the components it says are missing. I would post the pictures, but SO only lets me put two links right now.

What am I missing here? This is the first time I've found a problem I cant solve looking at answered questions, and I hope you all can help. Thank you.

Edit: I have metroframework in both my references node and in the header of my code. VS does recommend I remove it from my header, as it says it is not being used, but it is being used, its just throwing the errors.

I also seem to get a setup error, and I am not sure that I had it before. Image in gallery.

All images are in the folowing gallery. 
[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjzjy.jpg)

Comment: to you have the references not only added to the `using` in the header but added as well in the references node in the project..?

Comment: Can you link to an imgur gallery containing a picture of when you hover over one of the Metro controls? If it comes up with a suggestion to use a reference, click on that and it should be fixed

Comment: Did you try to clean/rebuild the solution? Also, restarting VS might help

Comment: Random thought: is the assembly you're referencing built with a compatible .NET framework version (i.e. equal or older) to the version your project is targeting? Or, perhaps, are you building to a specific 'bittedness' (x64 or win32) and the referenced assembly built for the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio sometimes acts up. Try any of the following:

1. Building the solution even with errors. This can get NuGet packages to refresh and that may be your problem.
2. Cleaning the solution and then building.
3. Restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Sometimes you have to go even further, by deleting the `.vs` folder within the solution directory that holds some cached data about the projects, but this should be one of the last resorts.

Comment: I've done all of this, but still no improvements, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

**You have the wrong project installed**. To fix your problem install `Metro Modern UI - Metro Framework` by [Dennis Magno from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/) (I assume that's the correct one because it has `MetroGrid` and `MetroDateTime`). If you use gui search for `metromodernui` in search box, or execute this

```
Install-Package MetroModernUI
```

---

#### For the record

[Here](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui) is original project which you probably had installed (now so that I looked at last screenshot). Installed using:

```
Install-Package ModernUI
```

[Here](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui) is another project you **don't** want to install (I thought you had this one originally) because it also doesn't have neither of those controls. Installed using:

```
Install-Package MetroFramework -Version 1.2.0.3
```

[Here](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui) is the project you probably want to install to resolve errors.

```
Install-Package MetroModernUI
```

"Conveniently", they all use the same namespace `MetroFramework`, hence the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click on the References folder on your project.
2. Select Add Reference.
3. Select the .NET tab (or select the Browse button if it is not a .NET Framework assembly).
4. Double-click the assembly containing the namespace in the error message.
5. Press the OK button.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto no, it is not _"completely irrelevant"_ as you put it, because Matt clearly states that if the assembly is **not** a .NET Framework assembly, you can use the Browse button to select any other assembly written in a .NET language.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow look at the picture in the question. The OP **has** the correct reference already

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is right and I agree on your point that this answer does not help solve the issues, I was just saying that your statement that you can only browse assemblys of the .NET framework is not correct.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow you are right there, I missed the comment on the browse part and forgot to add the part of the already added reference

Answer (score -1):

Try this command from your `Package Manager Console`

> `Update-Package`

Comment: I tried this, and got a message that all packages were up to date, so it preformed no action.

Comment: Hmmmm. Maybe do a reinstall. `Update-Package -Reinstall`